# Which kind of participle clause does "clarifying ....."stand for?

Tags: american-english

OP:(See the "How to Ask" page for help clarifying this question. )  does it equal (See the "How to ask" page for help and clarify this questiin) . And plus: It would be more correct if I add a comma before "clarifying" in the OP,right?

Answer (score 1):

no, See the "How to Ask" page for help clarifying this question. = See the "How to Ask" page for help (on) clarifying this question.

Comment: Could you tell me about redeced preposion grammar? I mean,when should I abbreviate preposition like that?

Comment: Here, HELP is a noun, and "Clarifying this question" is anohter noun clause as the help's topic (purpose)

Comment: It's my own example. (You should read more novels (on) improving your english skill). But I think it also can be like (you should read more novels and improve your english skill)=my example. You know,when the two actions have/modify the sam subject,then I could abbreviate the sentence by using participle clause/ing clause. But I think the OP and the theory I mentioned is not the same thing.

Comment: Maybe it is similar to this example( I have trouble doing sth) or (I am busy doing sth). You know it also can be wrote like ( I have trouble in doing sth)

Comment: I think I get it... I misunderstanded it ... (clarifying ...) functions as an adjective modifying the noun ( help)..